# C++11 Reference count smart pointer design

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am reading this,
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31529&seqNum=5
and author explain three types of smart pointer design (see pictures at the end of the post).

I believe current GCC, CLang and probably Visual C++ uses `smart pointers with control block`.

I can imagine why `intrusive reference counting` is not used, but what is the problem with second implementation - `smart pointer with pointer to pointer block`? There should be two pointer de-references, but smart pointer object size will be just half.

**smart pointer with control block**

[image: smart pointer with control block]

**smart pointer with pointer to pointer block**

[image: smart pointer with pointer to pointer block]

**smart pointer with intrusive reference counting**

[image]

Comment: Instead of believing, why don't you read the code and see what the implementations *actually* do?

Comment: can not check right now, but should be the one with control block. also the size is 16 bytes, e.g. two pointers.

Comment: When using make_shared, many implementations implement a memory layout like shown above for intrusive reference counting. This has the benfit of using only a single allocation but the drawback that a sole living weak_ptr will keep the whole memory allocated even no smart_ptr to its object exists anymore. See e.g. Scott Meyers, More Effective C++.

Comment: are you saying that make_shared will do different "layout" than auto up = std::unique_ptr(ptr);

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` doesn't perform any extra heap allocations, while `make_shared` does. So of course the memory layout will be different. If you mean `auto up = std::shared_ptr(ptr);` - then yes, it is a common implementation technique to have `make_shared` combine memory for the object itself, and for the control block, together into a single heap allocation, while `shared_ptr`'s constructor obviously can't do that (the allocation for the object has already happened).

Comment: I see and in case of `make_shared`, second pointer points to the address internal to the allocated block. (I actually tried this already and it seems that way)

Comment: Double dereferences are expensive, and so are fat pointers. Each could be better in some circumstances but not in others. Implementations have to select one technique, so I like to think that the selection is done after a careful consideration of all things and that the selected variant will provide the best solution for most people most of the time. In reality, who knows.

Comment: "smart pointer with control block" uses slightly more memory, but allows faster dereferencing of the smart pointer. With a pointer to pointer block you need an additional memory load of pObj_ from the SPimpl object before you can get the address of your real object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important reason is performance, `shared_ptr::get()` doesn't have to dereference a pointer to find the object address if it's stored directly inside the `shared_ptr` object.

But apart from performance, the `smart pointer with pointer to pointer block` implementation wouldn't support all the things you can do with `shared_ptr` e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> pi(new int(0));
std::shared_ptr<void> pv = pi;
std::shared_ptr<int> pi2 = static_pointer_cast<int>(pv);

struct A {
  int i;
};
std::shared_ptr<A> pa(new A);
std::shared_ptr<int> pai(pa, pa->i);

struct B { virtual ~B() = default; };
struct C : B { };
std::shared_ptr<B> pb(new C);
std::shared_ptr<C> pc = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(pb);
```

In these examples `pv`, `pai` and `pb` store a pointed that is not the same type as the pointer owned by the control block, so there must be a second pointer (which might be a different type) stored in the `shared_ptr` itself.

For `pv` and `pb` it would be possible to make it work, by converting the pointer stored in the control block to the type that needs to be returned. That would work in some cases, although there are examples using multiple inheritance that would not work correctly.

But for the `pai` example (which uses the aliasing constructor) there is no way to make that work without storing a pointer separate to the one in the control block, because the two pointers are completely unrelated types and you can't convert between them.

You said in a comment:

> I see and in case of make_shared, second pointer points to the address internal to the allocated block. (I actually tried this already and it seems that way)

Yes, that's correct. There is still a second pointer, but both poitners refer into the same block of memory. This has the advantage that only one memory allocation is needed instead of two separate ones for the object and the control block. Additionally, the object and control block are adjacent in memory so are more likely to share a cache line. If the CPU has got the ref-count in its cache already then it probably also has the object in its cache, so accessing them both is faster and means there is another cache line available to be used for other data.